# Async block makes all flow-refs inside async?

Tags: mule

Consider the following case:
I have a webservice that starts importing stuff from a source. I'd like to return 200 OK to the caller as soon as the call is accepted.
There few different flows that need to executed in the right order.

```
<flow name="startImport" >
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" path="startImport"/>
        <async>
            <flow-ref name="Country" />
            <flow-ref name="Account" />
            <flow-ref name="Contact" />
        </async>
</flow>
```

Well, this doesn't work, as all of the flows are executed at once.

How about wrapping it in an another flow like this?

```
<flow name="startImport" >
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" path="startImport"/>
        <async>
            <flow-ref name="startImport2" />
        </async>
</flow>

<flow name="startImport2" processingStrategy="synchronous" >
        <processor-chain>
            <flow-ref name="Country" />
            <flow-ref name="Account" />
            <flow-ref name="Contact" />
        </processor-chain>
</flow>
```

Nope, still the same result!

How can I stop the async-block making all the other flow-refs from turning async as well? I only want the first call to start asynchronously!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private flows invoked via  `flow-ref` will pick up the synchronicity of the in-flight event.

To change this you can change the `processingStrategy` of the flows you want to execute synchronously. Example:

```
<flow name="Country" processingStrategy="synchronous">

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up removing the flow refs and using vm-endpoints instead, like this:

```
<flow name="startImport" >
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" path="startImport"/>
        <async>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  doc:name="VM" path="import-all.service.in"/>
        </async>
</flow>

<flow name="startImport2" processingStrategy="synchronous" >
      <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  doc:name="VM" path="import-all.service.in"/>
      <flow-ref name="Country" />
      <flow-ref name="Account" />
      <flow-ref name="Contact" />
</flow>
```

Now it works like I'd expect it to work, it quickly returns from the call and lets the async flow do the heavy lifting.